# I get an error when trying to use the merge function:

Tags: r

I'm new to R. I get a factor level error when trying to run these lines of what appears to be very simple code:

```
Attendance_1415 <- merge(Locations_1415, Absences_1415,by=c("Employee_ID","Date"), all.x=TRUE) 
Attendance_1415 <- merge(Attendance_1415, PayCodes_1415, by=c("Employee_ID","Date"), all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: to merge factor variables, both should have the same levels

Comment: Please update your question to include a reproducible example, meaning code we can run to replicate your error. In this case we would need sample data for `Locations_1415`, `Absences_1415`, and `PayCodes_1415`. You can read more about reproducible examples at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269.